# User friendly parent/child routes for categories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to have URL like `www.mydomain.com/category/parent/child` so my routes are `get '/category/:name(/:name)' => 'categories#show'`

I got a table 'categories' like

```
> desc categories;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| public_id  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name       | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| root       | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I populate the database like this

```
Category.create(:public_id => 60, :name => "nues", :root => 0)
Category.create(:public_id => 61, :name => "artistiques", :root => 60)
Category.create(:public_id => 62, :name => "glamours", :root => 60)
Category.create(:public_id => 63, :name => "fetichiste", :root => 60)
Category.create(:public_id => 69, :name => "autres", :root => 60)
```

So if `root = 0` so it's a parent category. If `root > 0`the category is a child from the root value

My Categorie_Controller show action. The problem is that categories got the same name like 'Nature -> Others' and 'Portrait -> Others'. So my find_by_name doesn't work properly

```
def show
    if request.get?
    @photographs = Category.find_by_name(params[:name]).photographs
    end
end
```

Is-it possible to do what I want with my routes system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't pick the same name for the param variables.

```
# config/routes.rb
get '/category/:name(/:child_name)', to: 'categories#show'

# app/controllers/categories_controller.rb
def show
  # Now params[:name] and params[:child_name] are available
  # BTW: Only get requests will be routed anyways with your routes definition
  @photographs = if params[:child_name].present?
    parent = Category.find_by!(name: params[:name])
    Category.find_by!(name: params[:child_name], root: parent.id)
  else
    Category.find_by!(name: params[:name])
  end
end
```

Hope these hints help.

Additionally, you can see your incoming params by raising them in the controller action:

```
raise params.inspect
```

Comment: You're a genius, thanks! I didn't know we can use custom name for param variables in routes. I believed we have to use only db attribute name...